# Is Web 8's hotfix CD_8.1.1.2347 available for Java?

Tags: web8, broker

I'm migrating Tridion 2011 SP1 to SDL Web 8.
I have custom Java Tag Library which is using 2011 SP1's Broker API.

Because it's upgrading from old version, I use "In Process" API.
The custom Tag Library works fine with SDL Web 8's JAR files.

But when replacing JAR files with hotfix "CD_8.1.1.2347", it causes following error.

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException: null
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
        at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)
```

This error occurs at following code.

```
    for (Keyword children : keyword.getKeywordChildren()) {
    }
```

"CD_8.1.1.2317-2" is no problem.

"CD_8.1.1.2347"'s README.txt mentions only about .NET, but not about Java.

Is "CD_8.1.1.2347" available for Java?

Regards,

**UPDATE**

It turns out that ConcurrentModificationException is Java custom tag library's problem.

But there was another issue, which is following error log was output to Tomcat's localhost.log.

```
 java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.tridion.util.FileUtils
```

I contacted SDL Support, and it turns out it's the hotfix's defect, and I got corrected hotfix from SDL Support.

Comment: Sounds like a question for SDL Customer Support rather than for the Community.

Comment: There were 2 different issues. First, ConcurrentModificationException was Java custom tag library's problem. Another one was hotfix's defect. I got a corrected hotfix from SDL Support, and it works fine. I updated my question for detail.